# How to get a sum on a recursive infinite progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence :  $1,11,111,1111,\cdots$
so the formula is  $a(n) = a(n-1)\cdot 10 +1$, $a(1)=1$.
How can I get the formula of the partial sums? I think this is not a geometric or arithmetic progression so those sum formulas won't work here.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that without recursion,

$$a_n = \frac{10^{n-1} - 1}{9} = \frac{1}{9}\cdot10^{n-1} - \frac{1}{9}$$

I guess you could sum it up more easily like this. Summing up over $\frac{1}{9}\cdot10^{n-1}$ gives a geometric series, while summing up over $-\frac{1}{9}$ simply gives $-\frac{n}{9}$.